# Знак табуляции и *args в python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Всем доброго времени суток!

В ходе решения задачки появилось 2 вопроса:

1. В коде, описанном ниже, через **delim_csv** я ввожу с клавиатуры знак табуляции для
   определения разделителя csv файла, который буду записывать на диск,
   и передаю его в функцию test_var_args. Мне нужно, чтобы при return -
   мне вернулась строка вида "row[1] + '\t' + row[2] +" и т.д., но
   получаю вместо '\t' - пробел, что не очень хорошо, как мне кажется.
   Каким образом это можно побороть?
2. При отработке **of.write(str(str(test_var_args(*i)) + '\n'))** получаю в
   файл дубликат строки, а не записанные элементы файла tsv. Если
   указывать явно "row[1] + '\t' row[2] + '\n'", то отрабатывает
   корректно. Что не так - не могу понять. Почему не записываются элементы из tsv файла в csv файл...?

Заранее спасибо!

```
import csv
import os
import psycopg2

def test_var_args(*args):
    n = 0
    b = str('')
    while n < len(args):
        b = str(b + ("row[" + str(args[n]) + "]"))
        n += 1
        if n < len(args):
            b = str(b + ' ' + "+ " + delim_csv + " + ")
    return b

class Postgres:

    def __init__(
            self,
            db_name_v4='postgres',
            user_v4='postgres',
            password_v4='postgres',
            host_v4='127.0.0.1',
            port_v4=int(5432),
    ):
        self.main_db_name = db_name_v4
        self.main_user = user_v4
        self.main_password = password_v4
        self.main_host = host_v4
        self.main_port = port_v4
    def connect_main(self):
        conn = psycopg2.connect(
            dbname=self.main_db_name,
            user=self.main_user,
            password=self.main_password,
            host=self.main_host,
            port=self.main_port,
        )
        conn.autocommit = False
        return conn, conn.cursor()
    def close_connect(self):
        conn, cursor = self.connect_main()
        conn.close()

    def commit(self):
        conn, cursor = self.connect_main()
        conn.commit()

    def insert_to_main(self, element):
        conn, cursor = self.connect_main()
        cursor.execute(element)
        conn.commit()

postgres = Postgres()


delim_tsv = str(input("Whrite your delimeter from tsv: "))
delim_csv = str(input("Whrite your delimeter for csv: "))

this_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
filename_temp = str(input("Write your tsv-file name: "))
filename = ('C:\\New Folder\\' + filename_temp + '.tsv')
output_file_temp = str(input("Write your csv-file name: "))
output_file = ('C:\\New Folder\\' + output_file_temp + '.csv')

with open(filename, 'r') as f, open(output_file, 'w') as of:
    rd = csv.reader(f, delimiter=delim_tsv, quotechar='"')
    print('Write space separated list items for the new file: ')
    i = []
    for a in input().split():
        i.append(int(a))
    for row in rd:
        try:
            of.write(str(str(test_var_args(*i)) + '\n'))
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
    f.close()
    of.close()

postgres.insert_to_main("copy temp_table (column_1, column_2, column_3) from 'C:\\New Folder\\filename.csv' delimiter ' ' csv header encoding 'windows-1251'")
postgres.close_connect()
```

Comment: Попробуйте сократить объем кода, который воспроизводит проблему. На данный момент ваш вопрос и тем более самоответ бесполезны для сообщества, т.к. непонятна проблема, которую они решают.

Comment: `str(str(test_var_args(*i)) + '\n')` - не нужно десять раз оборачивать в `str`. У вас функция и так возвращает строку, достаточно просто сделать `test_var_args(*i) + '\n'`. По поводу таба - у меня на Python 3.6 из `input` приходит именно `'\t'`. Вы уверены что у вас получается пробел?

Comment: @insolor, да, возвращает не '\t', а ' '

Comment: @mkkik хорошо, учту в дальнейшем, спасибо!

Comment: Голосую за закрытие вопроса, т.к. тут два вопроса в одном.

Answer (score -1):

Первый вопрос остался открытым а второй решил следующим образом:

```
import csv
import os
import psycopg2
import transliterate


class Postgres:

    def __init__(
            self,
            db_name_v4='postgres',
            user_v4='postgres',
            password_v4='postgres',
            host_v4='127.0.0.1',
            port_v4=int(5432),
    ):
        self.main_db_name = db_name_v4
        self.main_user = user_v4
        self.main_password = password_v4
        self.main_host = host_v4
        self.main_port = port_v4

    def connect_main(self):
        conn = psycopg2.connect(
            dbname=self.main_db_name,
            user=self.main_user,
            password=self.main_password,
            host=self.main_host,
            port=self.main_port,
        )
        conn.autocommit = False
        return conn, conn.cursor()

    def close_connect(self):
        conn, cursor = self.connect_main()
        conn.close()

    def commit(self):
        conn, cursor = self.connect_main()
        conn.commit()

    def insert_to_main(self, element):
        conn, cursor = self.connect_main()
        cursor.execute(element)
        conn.commit()


postgres = Postgres()

this_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
filename_temp = str(input("Write your tsv-file name: "))
filename = ('C:\\New Folder\\' + filename_temp + '.tsv')
output_file_temp = str(input("Write your csv-file name: "))
output_file = ('C:\\New Folder\\' + output_file_temp + '.csv')

with open(filename, 'r') as f, open(output_file, 'w') as of:
    firstLine = f.readline()
    firstLine = firstLine.replace("\"", "")
    firstLine = firstLine.split("\t")
    print("List of elements from header with index: " + "\n")
    count_first_line = 0
    while count_first_line < len(firstLine):
        print(transliterate.translit(str(str(count_first_line) + " " + str(firstLine[count_first_line].replace(" ", "_"))), reversed=True))
        count_first_line += 1
    rd = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t', quotechar='"')
    print('Write space separated list items for the new file(numbering starts from 0): ')
    i = []
    for a in input().split():
        i.append(int(a))
    db_columns = ''
    db_columns_copy = ''
    for row in rd:
        try:
            l = 0
            s = ''
            while l < len(i):
                s = str(s + row[i[l]])
                l += 1
                if l < len(i):
                    s = str(s + '\t')
            of.write(s + '\n')
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
    f.close()
    of.close()
    l = 0
    while l < len(i):
        db_columns = transliterate.translit(str(db_columns + firstLine[i[l]].replace(" ","_") + " varchar(255)"), reversed=True)
        db_columns_copy = transliterate.translit(str(db_columns_copy + firstLine[i[l]].replace(" ","_")), reversed=True)
        l += 1
        if l < len(i):
            db_columns = str(db_columns + ' , ')
            db_columns_copy = str(db_columns_copy + ' , ')
    postgres.insert_to_main("create table " + output_file_temp + " (" + db_columns + ")")
    postgres.insert_to_main("copy " + filename_temp + " (" + db_columns_copy + ") from \'" + output_file + "\' delimiter \' \' encoding \'windows-1251\'")
    postgres.close_connect()
```